# Two separate handlers for same event

Tags: jquery, radio-button, styling, jquery-events

I'm styling my radio buttons with 'label' tags by using 'before' selector.
I'm using 'click' event for labels to make that clickable across all the browser(chrome doesn't support before/after elements to click).
There is an existing script which will show/hide some elements on clicking radio button.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm writing a script on 'click' event of lables. Existing show/hide functionality is not working properly because I'm trying to initiate click of radio while clicking label.

**What I need**

I need to write a script which shouldn't affect existing script(show/hide) and it should work in all the browsers.

**What I can't do**

1. I can't finish it simply by giving id and for attributes. :(
2. I can't customize existing script.

**What I think I can do**

1. I can modify HTML/CSS to design my radio by any other way. But there are lot of places to do changes. :(
2. Using "change" event instead of "click" for show/hide divs.

**Code sample**

```js
/*what I'm trying...*/
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]+label').on('click',function(){
    $(this).prev().click();
  });
});

/*existing script*/
$('input[name="fieldname"]').click(function(){
  if($('#fieldid').is(':checked')){
    $('#divid').show();
    $('#divid1').hide();
  } else if($('#fieldid1').is(':checked')){
    $('#divid1').show();
    $('#divid').hide();
  }
});
/*existing script*/
```

```css
.divs, input[type="radio"]{display:none;}

input[type="radio"]+label::before{
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background:red;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label::before{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <input type="radio" name="fieldname" id="fieldid" class="fieldclass" />
  <label>show textfield</label>
  <input type="radio" name="fieldname" id="fieldid1" class="fieldclass" />
  <label>show button</label>
  <div id="divid" class="divs"><input type="text" size="30"></div>
  <div id="divid1" class="divs"><input type="submit" value="button"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution, but check if you can place this after the existing click event code. Basically, I am trying to unbind the existing click event and rewrite it in another *document.ready* segment. Check if that is possible:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Unbind the existing click event
      $('input[name="fieldname"]').unbind( "click" );

      // if any label immediately after radio is clicked, call radio's click event
      $('input[type="radio"]').next('label').on('click',function(){
            $(this).prev('input[type="radio"]').click();
      });

      // radio is clicked
      // if the label next to radio says show textfield / show button
      // find the sibling div which has input of type this/that, and show/hide
      $('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){   
        /*if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show textfield') {
            $(this).siblings("div.divs").has('input[type="text"]').show();
            $(this).siblings("div.divs").has('input[type="submit"]').hide();        
        } else if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show button')    {
            $(this).siblings("div.divs").has('input[type="text"]').hide();
            $(this).siblings("div.divs").has('input[type="submit"]').show();
        }*/
        if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show textfield') {
            $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(0)").show();
            $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(1)").hide();      
        } else if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show button')    {
            $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(0)").hide();
            $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(1)").show();      
        }   

      }); /* end click */
    }); /* end doc.ready */
```

I have checked this in Firefox and Chrome, and the code is working on both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: Yes. I can place the new script after the old one.

Comment: Welcome @Anand...ok, that's great :)

Comment: The code sample I gave here is just a sample. This will not contain input[type="text"] or input[type="submit"].

Comment: ok...in that case you can change the if-else block inside the radio click event. I have assumed that the first radio checked will only show the first div, and the second radio checked will only show the second div:

if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show textfield') {
    $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(0)").show();
    $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(1)").hide();
} else if ($(this).next('label').html().trim().toLowerCase()=='show button') {
    $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(0)").hide();   
    $(this).siblings("div.divs:eq(1)").show();
} 
Working in chrome.

Comment: Oops, this is looking horrible! I will comment the old code and add the new one....sorry, not very familiar with commenting yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not allowed to edit the existing JS, you also **don't have to add any additional JS to it**.

Simply wrap your *titles* into `<span>`
and than both `<span>` and `<input>` into your `<label>` element:

```js
/* ABSOLUTELY NO NEED TO ADD ANYTHING */

/*existing script*/
$('input[name="fieldname"]').click(function(){
  if($('#fieldid').is(':checked')){
    $('#divid').show();
    $('#divid1').hide();
  } else if($('#fieldid1').is(':checked')){
    $('#divid1').show();
    $('#divid').hide();
  }
});
/*existing script*/
```

```css
.divs, input[type="radio"]{display:none;}

/* SIMPLY CHANGE `label` to `span` and you're done! */
input[type="radio"]+span::before{
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background:red;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+span::before{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Wrap INPUT and the new SPAN into LABEL -->

<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldname" id="fieldid" class="fieldclass" />
    <span>show textfield</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="fieldname" id="fieldid1" class="fieldclass" />
    <span>show button</span>
  </label>
  <div id="divid" class="divs"><input type="text" size="30"></div>
  <div id="divid1" class="divs"><input type="submit" value="button"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding code samples here. :)
The problem is there are hundreds of radio buttons across all the pages. :( I can't simply reconstruct all the html.

Comment: There would be around 1000 radio buttons in my web application. :(